# .htpasswd doesnt protect .txt files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

i have a basic auth protected directory with :

```
AuthType Basic 
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

every thing is ok and directories are not visible , and force to login  ,
but .txt files are visible directly in any browsers ,
i checked in every browser and its not some login remember problem
example :

```
test.com/password-dir/
```

is no visible
but

```
test.com/password-dir/1.txt
```

is visible

Comment: I don’t think that can be explained by the code you have shown so far. Do you have any rewriting configured on the root level, or anything like that, that might interfere?

Comment: no its has an empty htaccess in root folder , and cpanel is installed .

Comment: Can you give us a real URL to one of those text files, so we can check how it behaves for ourselves?

Comment: sorry its an international project and i have not permission to send direct link . any comments? is it possible its server cache or cloud cache ?

Comment: Sure, caching on some level could easily be part of the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every one who come here from google , or Other search mechanisms
I Finally Found The Problem and Fixed it .
When You are Using **Curl**
Its very strange on litespeed server with cache enabled , when you Request a Url with Authentication data ( user and password ) , even if you dont send Authentication data again , Server will always respond to you request .
in my case :

```
test/1.txt
```

was opened one time with auth data and responded to me , because of this , server always responded well even if im not sending auth data.

but when **CURL** request to another url link like:

```
test/2.txt
```

authentication data needed ;
so authentication doesnt have problem and worked well . it was just caching mechanism that let me visit/request the file again without auth data.